# NetworkManager can't update settings if Netplan config exists

Tags: networking, network-manager, dhcp, netplan

I am using 18.04.4. I configure an interface using netplan (/etc/netplan/enp0s3.yaml), set a static IP, and set the renderer as NetworkManager. My file looks like:

```
network:  
  version: 2  
  renderer: NetworkManager  
  ethernets:  
    enp0s3:  
      dhcp4: false  
      addresses:  
        - 192.168.1.197/24  
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1  
      nameservers:   
          addresses: [8.8.8.8]
```

After I run the following, I am able to see these changes in the Network Manager:
**netplan generate

netplan apply**

However, if I then change these settings in the Network Manager, the new settings will not persist after a reboot, and it will default back to the netplan config. How can I overwrite the netplan settings permanently from the Network Manager? For my purposes, I need to initially set the network settings from a program (currently using netplan) then allow the user to change it from the Network Manager.

Comment: FYI:  A fully upgraded *bionic* system will report itself as 18.04.5, so if you system is reporting itself as 18.04.4, you're well behind on updates (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ shows the ISO release, but installed systems upgrade to 18.04.5 before the date listed there) and thus could be potentially at security risk.. Please update (it could also be 18.04.4 was your installed release, and not you current release..)

Comment: Note that this is By Design - you would need to use a Network Manager keyfile as is posted in the answer to start the initial Network Manager config.  If you configure something via Netplan directly, it's no longer managed by Network Manager, which is as you would expect.  Unless you preload the configuration entirely into Network Manager.

Answer (score 0):

One approach:

Change the Netplan config to the normal (desktop-style) stub that let's Network Manager run the network connection. Don't add any interface or networking information.

```
network:
    version: 2
    renderer: NetworkManager
```

Use a [Network Manager keyfile](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nm-settings-keyfile.html) to add your inital networking config to Network Manager. Here's an example (taken directly from that linked site):

```
[connection]
id=Main eth0
uuid=27afa607-ee36-43f0-b8c3-9d245cdc4bb3
type=802-3-ethernet
autoconnect=true

[ipv4]
method=auto

[802-3-ethernet]
mac-address=00:23:5a:47:1f:71
```